# Panel box out side the application window

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I want show pannel box outside my application window. How can i do that? I have set my application window size as per my need.

Here is the code:

```
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" height="200" width="300">
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are making an Air application.

You should look at the [Window](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Window.html) class to open an additional window outside of your main app's window. Make your pop up panel class extend `Window`, then in your code create the panel and call it's `open()` method.